# open 'single form' subform to a specific record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to open a single record subform "frm_sample_cnv1" to a specific record. The record is specified by sample_id which is the primary key. I've tried the following method without success:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_combined_CNVs", , , "Forms!frm_combined_CNVs.frm_sample_cnv1.Form.[sample_id] = '" & sample_id & "'"
```

Also, frm_sample_cnv1 contains a linked subform that should automatically be filtered when frm_sample_cnv1 is set.  The Main form "frm_combined_CNVs" is unbound form.
Please suggest how to make this work.

Comment: If `sample_id` is a number then you do not require the single quotation field qualifiers. That is for string variables.

Comment: sample_id is also a string variable that contains the sample number. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error in your code.
Try the code below:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_combined_CNVs", , , "sampleid = '" & sample_id & "'"
```

Do try to include the reason why your code doesn't work or what error you receive next time.